# nslookup works with /etc/resolv.conf, ping and ssh don't

Tags: macos, network

In our local university network, I have (obtained by DHCP) the following setup in /etc/resolv.conf:

```
search a.domain.com b.domain.com domain.com
nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver y.y.y.y
```

The settings are the same in System Preferences as well.
The following problem occurs:

```
nslookup server
```

works, and is using one of the nameservers to correctly ask for server.a.domain.com.
If I try to ping however,

```
ping server
```

fails with unreachable host.

```
ping server.a.domain.com
```

works. Manually adding server with the ip address obtained by nslookup to /etc/hosts makes ping work too, but this "solution" circumvents the nameservers and is thus not ideal (and I would have to add about 20 other entries as well). Any idea what is causing this? Why does ping not use the results of nslookup/the searchdomains?

```
ssh server
```

also fails, which is the real problem/inconvenience.

I already added AlwaysUseSearchDomains to mDNSResponder, but this fix only helps the problem when using server.foo.

I'm using OS X Lion 10.7.3.

Comment: Ping packets may be blocked by network equipment.  Same thing with ssh packets - they may not want you to do what you do.

Comment: See solution below, that was not the issue.

Comment: "Unreachable host" means a network connectivity problem (or ICMP blocked), not DNS resolution problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, did you read the comments at the top of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

```
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
```

The correct solution is to add the search domains via the Network panel in System Preferences as described [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/14127.html).

Comment: I did. The search domains are automatically entered in the Network panel in System Preferences per DHCP configuration (and are thus greyed out and not changeable). The exact same values/configuration are/is found in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, then.  I get both my Ethernet and WiFi settings via DHCP and can change my search domains via the System Preferences panel.

Comment: The searchdomains are correct in System Preferences and /etc/resolv.conf - the problem is, that ping and ssh aren't using it. If they would use the output of nslookup, everything would work fine, but somehow, they don't. They lookup /etc/hosts, though.

Comment: I manually added the searchdomains (although they were greyed out) one by one via System Preferences and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  The solution I used was to create an /etc/resolver directory.  Inside that directory, create a file named for each domain you wish to resolve for.  Inside each file there should be two lines

```
nameserver 10.0.100.2
domain  home.cainmanor.com
```

The file above would be named /etc/resolver/home.  It may need to be named home.cainmanor.com, but I can't test it right now.

Good luck!

Comment: I got it working by setting the searchdomains via System Preferences one by one, overriding the DHCP settings which OS X failed to parse correctly obviously. I couldn't try your solution, but thanks!

Comment: This approach works nicely for when your corporate VPN client does the wrong thing with respect to transient system preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I answered this somewhere else, because it was a simple fix for me, and I couldn't find the answer that worked for me anywhere else.

After restarting mDNSResolver dozens of times as recommended on other threads:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I finally tried something else. I disabled Wi-Fi and deleted all of my preferred networks. Then I reestablished the Wi-Fi connection and everything worked okay:

1. Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Wi-Fi (on the left)
2. 'Turn Wi-Fi Off' then select 'Advanced'
3. Delete the Wi-Fi connection you're having trouble with (or all of
   them if you like). Do this by selecting the Wi-Fi network you want to delete and pressing "-"
4. Click 'Apply' and 'OK'
5. Turn Wi-Fi back on.
6. Select your Wi-Fi network and log in again.

This is what finally worked for me. It probably should have been the first thing I tried, but I'm a Linux guy and I look at console fixes first.

Comment: This has worked like a charm for me after banging my head trying to solve this for a while. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I believe, the problem lies within the searchdomains configuration: ping/ssh are trying to use `gethostbyname2()` which fails because *named* is not running anymore (in Lion at least) and `/etc/resolv.conf` with the configured searchdomains is thus ignored. `/etc/hosts` is the last resort for `gethostbyname2()` and thus ssh works again with proper entries in `/etc/hosts`. Should be fixed by Apple imho.</strike>

Manually adding the searchdomains one by one fixed it, see solution above.

Comment: When I add a search domain to my WiFi connection (which is configured via DNS) in OS 10.7.3 via the System Preferences -> Network panel, it is used by ping and ssh just as I would expect.  I do not touch /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/hosts manually/directly, but the changes from System Preferences are reflected in /etc/resolv.conf automatically.  OS X does a lot of things differently than other Unix systems and this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks, this got it working by adding the searchdomains manually one by one, see my comment on your suggested solution above.

Comment: Adding search domains did not fix the issues... Any one else got another solution?

Comment: How did you add them?

Answer (score 1):

I get this issue every so often, when my Mac Book Pro (OS X version 10.10.1) has been asleep. Wake it up & I can't ssh using hostname of machines on my network (and ping doesn't work either). nslookup works fine. Can't see any relevant messages in /var/log. Just leave it a few minutes & hey presto it works again .....